# Media files like invoices randomly deleted from harddrive

Tags: shopware, shopware6

We observe that randomly some files from the media folder get lost/deleted. We noticed this first with pdf invoices, that couldn't be downloaded any more through the administration. It turns out that the physical file did not exist anymore.

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this issue?
Is there some sort of "cleanup" task in Shopware that could be responsible for this behaviour?

Comment: There should be no automated task that deletes files from the file system. Is it just documents (e.g. invoices) or other files as well? There's a CLI command `media:delete-unused` which will actually delete files. I take it you never executed that one?

Comment: It is not only documents (at least it seems so), but also a custom CSV-file for example. Did not observe it for images until now...
The mentioned command is exactly such a hint I was looking for to search for occurences in some pipelines etc. to verify.
I *think* we do not use it, but will check that.